Followup intents can only be called twice?
I am doing a simple questionnaire on dialogflow essentials.
10 Questions.
Answers on a degree of 1 to 4
Answers can be postponed.
Questionnaire tells you how many postponed answers you have when you reach the last one. Ideally adding an intent to go over the missing answers in a bit
My issue is that followup intents are not recognized after the second call
I had them all as separate intents and it works beautifully but it gets hang up when they are followup intents and there is more than 2 replies.
Current situation
Start questionnaire
First Answer
Second Answer
Third Answer gets picked up by Default Backup intent 

Situation if they are unrelated intents.
Start questionnaire
First Answer
Second Answer
Third Answer
Later
Fourth Answer
LaterX6
Agent replies that there are 7 missing answers and wether you want to go over them from now on 

Same answers and the answer intent is triggered by just numbers from 1 to 4 or a set of words associated(strongly agree - 4, strongly disagree - 0)
I see them as follow-up intents because they are related but I don't see a way of letting me call a follow up intent three times in a row or more.
I know I can prevent them from being triggered randomly by checking if the questionnaire context exists or not
What am I missing?
Answering myself. Make sure that the followup intent has at least all of the input contexts it requires. If it takes context1 & context2 it needs to output context1 & context2 at least

Answering myself. Make sure that the followup intent has at least all of the input contexts it requires. If it takes context1 & context2 it needs to output context1 & context2 at least

Hi @dot,  I have posted your comment as a community wiki solution so that anyone who faces a similar issue in the future can benefit from it. Do consider accepting and upvoting the answer, also feel free to edit the answer.

Hi @kiran. Just saw your reply and accepted it. I am starting out on dialogflow but will keep an eye on things I can help on

As @dot mentioned:

To solve the above  issue,  make sure that the followup intent has at least all of the input contexts it requires. If it takes context1 &
context2 it needs to output context1 & context2 at least.

For more information refer to these link1 and link2.
Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.
Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.
